# Matplotlib: How to change de color and width of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I would like to change the color or the width of the axes of a plot.

For example, from this: 
[image: First image]

I would like to get: 
[image: Final image]

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `spines` attribute of your axis:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)

for side in ax.spines.keys():  # 'top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'
    ax.spines[side].set_linewidth(5)

plt.plot(numpy.arange(10))
plt.show()
```